# Using "precomputed" distance matrices as input to scikit-learn clustering metrics

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, hyperparameter-tuning, distance

Is there any validity to using a distance matrix instead of the raw points with metrics such as `davies_bouldin_score` and `calinski_harabasz_score`? Both functions will take any input with length `n_samples`. For some reason using a precomputed distance matrix seems to produce reasonable results, at least for the former.

I know scikit's implementation of Silhouette explicitly allows for a distance matrix, but these functions are not that way.